# jquery: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).error is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery on my page and don't have problem with other parts. Even $.post and $.get are working fine.

Now I am trying to evaluate if an image has any problems and tried this code:

```
$("#bib").error(function(){
   //nothing now 
});
```

I am wondering why I  get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).error is not a function
at app.js:53
(anonymous) @ app.js:53
```

As you see I have shortened the code to isolate the problem but you get the whole idea. At the moment these jquery sources are included inside the page:

**https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js**

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Looks like it was removed in 3.0.  Works ok in 2.4, then not in 3.0 (using jsfiddle).  Try the `.on` version as detailed here: https://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: [`.error()`](https://api.jquery.com/error/): "_As of jQuery 1.8, the .error() method is deprecated. Use .on( "error", handler ) to attach event handlers to the error event instead._"

Comment: @Andreas deprecated doesn't mean removed.  Can you find where they removed it?  Doesn't state on the API page.

Comment: @Andreas nvm, found it here: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

Comment: @freedomn-m It's deprecated so I wouldn't use it anymore, regardless of its actual removal :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this instead (as stated earlier, .error has been removed).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#bib").on('error', function(){
   //nothing now 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the jquery upgrade guide at: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

> **Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed**
>
> These methods are shortcuts for event operations, but had several API limitations. The event `.load()` method conflicted with the ajax `.load()` method. The `.error()` method could not be used with `window.onerror` because of the way the DOM method is defined. If you need to attach events by these names, use the `.on()` method, e.g. change `$("img").load(fn)` to `$("img").on("load", fn)`.